# Different SeekBar vertical padding on different devices

Tags: android, padding, seekbar

I faced a problem with a Seekbar vertical padding. I tried to set it to 8dp via XML or via code by `.setPadding(...)` but at runtime this value is different on different devices. Both devices have the same resolution and density.

Here are two screenshots:

Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro, API 22
[image: Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro, API 22]

Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X, API 24
[image: Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X, API 24]

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
                android:id="@+id/playback_speed_slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="4"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/playback_speed_title"/>
```

Why is this happening? How do I make the vertical padding the same?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I've tested the app via emulator on API 19, 23 and 24 and decided to make a simple workaround:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        playbackSpeedSlider.setPadding(2 * padding, padding, 2 * padding, padding);
    else
        playbackSpeedSlider.setPadding(2 * padding, 0, 2 * padding, 0);
```

It seems that for me it solves the issue but I didn't test this solution on all supported API's and am not sure that it is a good way. How do you think about this solution? Anyway, does anybody have an idea why the described issue happens?

Comment: Show the SeekBar XML file/s

Comment: @JonGoodwin did it